# Leaflet OnWheel Event

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to fire an event when the mouse wheel is used:

```js
map.on('mousewheel', function() {
  console.log('foo');
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work, nor does "wheel".  Any ideas?

Comment: No, that is for Google maps, not leaflet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could draw some inspiration from [Leaflet source code handling the zoom on mousewheel](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/handler/Map.ScrollWheelZoom.js) and listen to the `mousewheel` events on the map container. Something like:

```js
L.DomEvent.on(map.getContainer(), 'mousewheel', function() {
  console.log("zoom", map.getZoom())
});
```

And a demo

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([35.772219, -78.675272], 10);

L.DomEvent.on(map.getContainer(), 'mousewheel', function() {
    console.log("zoom", map.getZoom())
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 100px"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, I wanted to post the same thing.